# Show error messages on top of form ? Or beside each individual fields?

Tags: error-reporting

Which approach do you all think is better?

Answer (score 3):

Next to each field, highlighting each field in a distinctive color or with an easily distinguishable mark, so it's self evident where the problems are, especially on a long form. Also place a help icon next to each failure providing more information in case it's needed by some users. In addition, do not forget to preserve the data that's correct in between failures.

Answer (score 1):

I put a summary of the errors at the top of the form that gives details as to **why** a field value is incorrect such as "Field1 is Required and must be an integer". I also add visual indicators on the field that errored, typically an asterisk next to the field or changing the color of the input area.

Answer (score 0):

It will always depend on the situation, but...

I prefer to do a non-obtrusive indicator (* perhaps) beside each field and show more detailed messages or a summary message at the top (or bottom) of the form with longer forms.

<strike>If the form is shorter, you can probably get away without providing a "summary".</strike> I changed my mind on this, you should probably provide a summary.

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the field with an error is important, definitely.  However, a summary at the top letting the user know that there are errors below can be helpful for a long form. Additionally, you can put more details in the top summary section that you might not have room for below.

Answer (score 0):

We supply a small indicator next to each field with an error.  When you roll over the indicator a tool tip gives you what needs to be fixed.  We then also give a summary at the smae time so they can see all of the errors they need to fix.